# Finding the language generated by this grammar

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata, formal-grammars, chomsky-hierarchy

I'm having problems with this. Can someone help me please.

Find the language generated by this grammar over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$:

> $S\rightarrow BAB\mid CAB$
>
> $BA \rightarrow BC$
>
> $CA \rightarrow AAC$
>
> $CB \rightarrow AAB$
>
> $A\rightarrow 0$
>
> $B \rightarrow 1$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to start doing it

Comment: Try doing some derivations to find a common pattern between the words you obtain, maybe.

Comment: Thanks! I tried but... nothing yet

Comment: If you use the starting rule $S\rightarrow CAB$, you will find that only one word is possible. Now try finding 4 different words with the other starting rule and I'm sure you will find a pattern. If not, maybe you should work on the basics of context-sensitive grammars.

Comment: Thank you! I wil try

Comment: I'm stuck. I did this but  I think It's wrong
L(G) = {w ∈ Σ ∗ | S ⇒+ w}  |
L¹(G¹) = {SM An Bn CN | n >= 1 e (m = 0 or m = 1)} @Nathaniel

Comment: https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the starting rule is $S\rightarrow CAB$. Then the only possible derivation is:

$$S\rightarrow CAB \rightarrow AACB \rightarrow AAAAB \rightarrow^* 00001$$

That means that most of the work is done with the other starting rule. To find any derivated word, we can start by noting that the nonterminal symbol $C$ cannot be rewrited as a terminal symbol. It means that we can consider replacing $A$'s with $0$'s and $B$'s with $1$'s in words written with only $A$'s and $B$'s. Let's try to find some derivated words:

$$S\rightarrow BAB\rightarrow BCB\rightarrow BAAB\rightarrow BCAB\rightarrow BAACB$$

Now we can conclude that $101\in L$ and $1001\in L$ (because we reached $BAB$ and $BAAB$), but at $BAACB$, two rules are possible.

- $BAACB\rightarrow BAAAAB$ (so $100001\in L$)
- $BAACB \rightarrow BCACB$

Let's continue the the last derivation (taking shortcuts at the end):

$$BCACB\rightarrow BAACCB\rightarrow BAACAAB\rightarrow BAAAACAB\rightarrow BAAAAAACB\rightarrow BA^8B \rightarrow BCA^7B\rightarrow^*BA^{14}CB\rightarrow^*BA^{16}B$$
That means that $10^81\in L$ and $10^{16}1\in L$.

I think you can find a pattern from here to find the words of $L$ beginning with a $1$. The difficult part is showing that no other word is in $L$ than those ones.

Comment: Thank you! Now I will try to understant how you did it. But this already helped me a lot. My problem was I needed an example to understand how to do it. Now I have a lot work to do to understant it. Thank you again